# how to return the sum as an array of the numbers that have the most appearances

Tags: java

You are giving an array representing a list of non-negative integers.
Write a function `findMostAppearances()` to return the sum as an array of the numbers that have the most appearances.
constraints:

- a: `0 <= list.length =< 100`
- b: `2 <= list[i] <= 100`

This is one my interview question and till this day I still don't know what the question want.

1. What does it mean when it say return the sum as an array of the numbers that have the most appearances
2. What does the a. and b. have to do with that? can anyone tell me?

Comment: I think best is to ask the interviewer what they wanted to know with the question. The asked the question, so they should be able to explain

Comment: That's a good practice to ask questions upon solving interview tasks. Don't hesitate to ask your interviewer to clarify necessary points.

Comment: a) The array has between 0 and 100 elements. b) The elements are between 2 and 100 inclusive.

Comment: The constraints are just that—problem boundaries. The list has 0-100 entries. Each entry is 2-100. They don’t have anything to do with each other besides setting some knowns. The question to ask is what is meant by “the most appearances”.

Comment: okay problem boundaries I get it it use to minimize the chances of occurent

Answer (score 0):

First I answer your second question.

- a. means that input array contains less then 100 elements.
- b. means that vakue of element is between 2 and 100

whole task is to find most common element of array and if multiply its value by number of appearances.

For example if you have `[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]` as input, most common element is `3` it appears 4 times in input array while `1` appears twice and `2` only once. So result be `3 * 4`.

Comment: Three appears three times in `[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4]`.

Comment: okay thank man I think I will ask my interviewer more time to clarify this question